# How can I get a symmetric bracket with xy-pic?

Tags: xy-pic

```
% Compiled by XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,pdf]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{xy}
,(0,0)="A"
,(10,0)="B";"A" **\frm{^\}}
\end{xy}
\end{document}
```

generates an asymmetric bracket, how can I get a symmetric one?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site please post a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Btw: nowadays things are a lot easier if you switch to tikz instead. Tikz-cd is equivalent to xy

Comment: `$\overbrace{\hspace{40pt}}$` unless you need more in the `xy` picture, which you should then show.

Comment: From the Xy-pic manual: braces are just the standard plain TeX large braces inserted correctly in Xy-pic pictures with the ‘nib’ aligned with the reference point of the object they brace.

Comment: To daleif: Thanks, I've found solution through tikz-cd;

Comment: To egreg: Actually, I did read that words in the manual , but I don't understand what's the meaning of 'nib', and don't know how to adjust the bracket

Comment: Remember to use @name when you talk to a specific person, then they'll know